# Find an exception that gets caught away

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, stack-trace, throw

### Original question

Given the following method that is part of a library (so it cannot be edited) (also, `A()` is private so it cannot be called outside of `m()`):

```
void m() {
    try {
        A();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        B();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When calling `m()`, `A()` generates an `Exception e` and so `B()` is executed. However, `B()` also throws an exception that is then passed up (instead of `e` which would be passed up a line later).

Is it possible to find the `Exception e`? Perhaps using some smart Reflection or a multithreading pause-and-go approach?

### Explanation of why I chose the best answer, and what else may be helpful

Makoto's answer:

> `e` is lost because any exception that is thrown will cause execution to complete abruptly.

is the correct answer to my question (i.e. it is not programmatically possible to retrieve the `Exception e`).

However, I would like to point out that Sean Patrick Floyd's comment:

> If you can't change the code, your only chance is to use a debugger and set a breakpoint inside the catch block.

and Pinkie Swirl's comment:

> Note that through debugging one could still see e and its information (stack trace etc..)

actually helped me solve my problem: through a debugger (the exception in question I was getting was an SQLException, so I really needed to know what it was to fix my problems).

Comment: If you can't change the code, your only chance is to use a debugger and set a breakpoint inside the catch block. But short of that, you'll never see that exception without changing the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is lost because any exception that is thrown will cause execution to [complete abruptly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6).

Consider this (valid code):

```
void m() throws Exception {
    try {
        A();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        B();
        throw e;
    }
}

private void B() {
    throw new RuntimeException("No!!!!");
}

private void A() throws Exception {
    throw new RuntimeException("Do I make it??");
}
```

The statement calling `B()` will cause the entire method `m()` to complete abruptly, since an exception was thrown.  This means that *nothing* in this current code block has access to `e` anymore.

To look at it from another angle, if you were to flip the order of statements inside of the `catch`...

```
void m() throws Exception {
    try {
        A();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
        B();
    }
}
```

...the call to `B()` would be considered unreachable, as the compiler can guarantee that `B()` will never be executed.  The same thing is happening here, with the caveat that the compiler *can't* determine if `B()` is absolutely guaranteed to throw an exception during its execution.

Comment: Note that through debugging one could still see e and its information (stack trace etc..)

Comment: @PinkieSwirl:  Yes, but no statement inside of the `catch` does anything with `e`.  It falls on the floor, effectively.

Comment: yes I know, just wanted to add that, if the OP has an option to do that, since he didn't specify that in his question.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl If with debugging you mean inserting or changing anything inside `m()`, then no. But I have the option to monitor the `Thread` in which `m()` is executed. Is there anything I can do with that perhaps? Is it possible to get the last thrown `Exception` of a `Thread` or the one currently being caught?

Comment: With debugging I mean execute your code in a debug modus, for example where you can set break points and step through the code step by step.

Comment: @Infima To answer directly, no.  Not unless you alter the code to do something with that caught exception.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Ah yes thank you, I had misunderstood the first time, but I suddenly understood what you meant after SeanPatrickFloyd's comment. I will try it!

Comment: @Makoto This was what I was expecting unfortunately, but thank you. I saw there was an UncaughtExceptionHandler in Java, it would be great if there was a direct ExceptionHandler to inject behavior (but I understand that this would be bad practice due to the huge performance penalty).

Answer (score 1):

Under most debuggers, e.g. [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-exception-breakpoints.html) you can set a breakpoint on when an exception is **thrown**, rather than handled.

You can also filter the class or other conditions on that throw statement.